# RelativeLayout inside of ScrollView - Android

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am changing my whole layout for this activity from a `TableLayout` to `RelativeLayout` for various reasons.  I have 10 "rows" I want inside of this `RelativeLayout` but right now I am just trying to get one row working.  After that 1 row is working, I will implement the other 9.

There are 4 columns in each row and right now only the first column is displaying and not the last 3.  Below is the code and screenshot.  The "red x" is the first column that is displaying.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >    

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/points"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".25"
                        android:textSize="9sp"
                        android:gravity="left" 
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/percentage"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:textSize="9sp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_score"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".45"
                        android:textSize="9sp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#000001" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answerColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/verseColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"  /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Question"  /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Answer"  /> 
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? You should upvote or comment why they didnt work. Share that SO love.

Comment: Hey @D.Tran, I see some good answers down below that I am anxious to test out!  Unfortunately, this afternoon has been busy but I plan on testing the answers below first thing in the morning when I have some time.  I will definitely upvote, comment and share that SO love when I get some time.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read it correctly and you are referring to this ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"  /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Image"   /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Question"  /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Answer"  /> 
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Your TextView's layout_width was set to 0dip when you need a wrap_content or static width. Also your TextView q1Question was not attached to the right of ImageView q1Image. Unless of course you wanted it stacked ontop of the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your views inside of your imageView have a width of 0dip and no weight. Could you correct that ?

Also, you could remove the weights on the TableRows and set them to match_parent.