# RelativeLayout doesn't show all buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I am not able to fit all my buttons on the screen? The last row and a half of buttons are off of screen? the final layout looks a bit different I've made custom buttons and there are secondary functions to most buttons but I've simplified the code to eliminate all possible mistakes not relating directly to my problem. I'd like the buttons to both fill and stay on the screen (I'd post a picture of my layout but my reputation is too low)

**RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_below="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImageView"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b11" />

    //...buttons

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b95"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b85"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b94"
        android:text="@string/b95" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LinearLayout(LinearLayout+GridLayout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImageView"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/GridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="9"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b11" />

        //...buttons are the same, I just erased the following RelativeLayout attributes:
-android:layout_below
-android:layout_toRightOf
-android:layout_alignParentBottom

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b95"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b95" />

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

http://postimg.org/image/wvcl7rfer/eeef02dd/

Here's the solution that worked for me (I haven't tried GridView nor TableLayout)
It's the one from BrOtherSOul. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImageView"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/sample" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b13" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b15" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b21" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b22" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b23" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b24" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b25" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b31" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b32" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b33" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b34"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b34" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b35"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b35" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b41"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b41" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b42" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b43"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b43" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b44"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b44" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b45"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b45" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b51"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b51" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b52"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b52" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b53"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b53" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b54"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b54" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b55"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b55" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b61"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b61" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b62"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b62" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b63"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b63" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b64"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b64" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b65"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b65" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH15"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b71"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b71" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b72"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b72" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b73"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b73" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b74"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b74" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b75"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b75" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH17"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b81"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b81" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b82"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b82" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b83"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b83" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b84"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b84" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b85"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b85" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH19"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b91"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b91" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b92"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b92" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b93"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b93" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b94"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b94" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b95"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="@string/b95" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

http://postimg.org/image/ltromjjpp/5ad91d61/

Comment: Post a link to some picture/s. We will put the picture/s back here.

Comment: If you are using bunch of buttons then you should add it dynamically. Or you can use Gridview.

Comment: You can also include your RelativeLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: Check this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759845/relativelayout-inside-of-scrollview-android

Comment: use gridview or tablelayout

Comment: Lokking at the huge amount of buttons, you should add a ScrollView so that even for devices with smaller screens all of them will b visible.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/3qusfdlap/ea9037c3/

Comment: Scroll down for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking your `GridLayout` to wrap its content on the vertical side. It did exactly that and has to go beyond the screen to do that. `GridLayout` is intended to prevent nested layouts but it looks like you'll have to do exactly that. Try ditching the `GridLayout` and create one `LinearLayout` for each row of button, all of this in a `LinearLayout`.
It's dirty I know but ... (They should've supported weight)
This solution will work on the vertical side for every screen you'll run it on. You can do the same for the width (I just solved the vertical problem)

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_below="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImageView"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/sample" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/1stRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

 //.... Your buttons

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/2ndRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

 //.... Buttons again

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LastRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Sincerely,
Your savior :)

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll view dude

```
        <ScrollView
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        // here u can add your all button or edit text or whatever u want to add just add 

        </ RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should get rid of the useless outer RelativeLayout.

Comment: yes but this is for @Mathieu_Roth i.e Mathieu_Roth exactly recognize about the place of scroll view that's y out this and when Mathieu_Roth apply this code then Mathieu_Roth is automatically  aware for this :)

Comment: It's useles... and lowers the performance of the layout. Just move the original RelativeLayout INSIDE the ScrollView (no need for a LinearLayout, then). OR remove the outer RelativeLayout and leave the LinearLayout, as you prefer. The ScrollView has to be the first container of all

Comment: use linear layout with android:orientation="vertical" i.e all layout view is automatically below and not want any reference like      android:layout_below="" not need for this

Comment: But then you loose the use of `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b11"` (and all the other relative positioning). He's making columns of buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, English is not my native thong and I'm pretty new to programming. The Scrollview works fine (I've tried it with the nested relative layout) anyway, sadly a scroll is not an option given the specifications I was given for this project.

Comment: but without scroll view how can u see all button on one screen itself dude

Comment: In the end it's suppose to look something like that http://blogimg.goo.ne.jp/user_image/4a/b2/74645b7dd7e969e915d64d8fad080713.png

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/result"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/result"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImageView"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b11" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b12"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b11"
            android:text="@string/b12" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b13"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b12"
            android:text="@string/b13" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b14"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b13"
            android:text="@string/b14" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b15"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b14"
            android:text="@string/b15" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b21"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b11"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b21" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b22"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b12"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b21"
            android:text="@string/b22" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b23"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b13"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b22"
            android:text="@string/b23" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b24"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b14"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b23"
            android:text="@string/b24" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b25"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b15"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b24"
            android:text="@string/b25" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b31"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b21"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b31" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b32"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b22"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b31"
            android:text="@string/b32" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b33"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b23"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b32"
            android:text="@string/b33" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b34"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b24"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b33"
            android:text="@string/b34" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b35"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b25"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b34"
            android:text="@string/b35" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b41"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b31"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b41" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b42"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b32"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b41"
            android:text="@string/b42" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b43"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b33"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b42"
            android:text="@string/b43" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b44"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b34"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b43"
            android:text="@string/b44" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b45"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b35"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b44"
            android:text="@string/b45" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b51"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b41"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b51" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b52"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b42"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b51"
            android:text="@string/b52" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b53"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b43"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b52"
            android:text="@string/b53" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b54"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b44"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b53"
            android:text="@string/b54" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b55"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b45"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b54"
            android:text="@string/b55" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b61"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b51"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b61" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b62"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b52"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b61"
            android:text="@string/b62" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b63"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b53"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b62"
            android:text="@string/b63" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b64"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b54"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b63"
            android:text="@string/b64" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b65"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b55"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b64"
            android:text="@string/b65" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b71"
            style="@style/ButtonTextWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b61"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b71" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b72"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b62"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b71"
            android:text="@string/b72" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b73"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b63"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b72"
            android:text="@string/b73" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b74"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b64"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b73"
            android:text="@string/b74" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b75"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b65"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b74"
            android:text="@string/b75" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b81"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b71"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b81" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b82"
            style="@style/ButtonTextBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b72"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b81"
            android:text="@string/b82" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b83"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b73"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b82"
            android:text="@string/b83" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b84"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b74"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b83"
            android:text="@string/b84" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b85"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b75"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b84"
            android:text="@string/b85" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b91"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b81"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/b91" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b92"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b82"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b91"
            android:text="@string/b92" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b93"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b83"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b92"
            android:text="@string/b93" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b94"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b84"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b93"
            android:text="@string/b94" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b95"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b85"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b94"
            android:text="@string/b95" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. The Scrollview works fine, sadly a scroll is not an option given the specifications I was given for this project

Answer (score 0):

Use linearlayout for the every three buttons ,so you can easily achieve your requirements.

```
<linearlayout

orientation=horizantal>
<button1>
<button2>
<button3>

</linearlayout>
```

use like that...

Answer (score 0):

Just add scroll view before relative layout

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. The Scrollview works fine, sadly a scroll is not an option given the specifications I was given for this project

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap you relative layout in ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. The Scrollview works fine, sadly a scroll is not an option given the specifications I was given for this project

Answer (score 0):

**First One:**

Never create huge number of  buttons inside your Layout using XML. In case you want to generate huge button then do it `dynamically` or use `GridView`

**Second One:**
If you create huge number of buttons inside Xml then dont forgot to use ScrollView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            // Your buttons

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```